# IOS: custom view for landscape and portrait in tab bar application

Tags: iphone, ios, landscape-portrait

I have a tab bar application, in one tab I have a view that has a different item(look) for landscape and portrait. my question is how can I handle this feature.
Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue. You can just check orientation by:

```
 UIViewController* vc = //your current view controller
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = vc.interfaceOrientation;
 //   NSLog(@"orientation %@",orientation);
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){...}
```

inside the if statement setup desired layout. If you have it in nib file you can substitude the whole view by self.view = portairtView; which can be defined and in the same nib. You can do same thing with an inner part of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle them as you would normally do using

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Comment: y question is about nib file and view on it.